# Default field values in force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Where am I going wrong? I am trying to make defaultFieldValues dynamic by adding a variable.

When I try this code, the fields do not default:

```
var strNewPhone ="{ 'Phone': '999-999-9999'}";
var createAcountContactEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createAcountContactEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact",
        "recordTypeId" : selectedRID,
        "defaultFieldValues"    : strNewPhone  
    });
```

when I try the below snippet, it works:

```
var createAcountContactEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createAcountContactEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact",
        "recordTypeId" : selectedRID,
        "defaultFieldValues"    : {
         'Phone' : '999-999-9999'
}  
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by fails? It fails to compile? it fails to run? it gives any error? or logic doesnt work?

Comment: Have you tried, 
var strNewPhone ={ 'Phone': '999-999-9999'} --> without the double quotes?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal: By Fails I mean the phone number do not default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to the fact that you are defining `strNewPhone` as a String (its value is enclosed by double quotes).

You should define it as an Object:

```
var strNewPhone = { Phone: '999-999-9999'};
```

Comment: Thanks POZ! As suggested by @the_phantom and you, I was setting it as a string. It should be an object. Updated code: This works               
var strNewPhone ={'Phone': '999-999-9999'};